# I am unable to delete this question, it's marked duplicate, I am only able to flag

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586436/please-delete-this

Please delete this, this is the link.

I am unable to remove a question, it is marked as duplicate and I am receiving downvotes. I am only able to flag.

Comment: The people answering put time into answering, it's not really fair on them to delete it is it?

Comment: Its a duplicate , what can i do, i am losing points like   9, 8 , 7   in every 5 mins

Comment: Be more careful to do proper research in future. Note that this meta post most likely excacerbates this situation by drawing attention to your poorly researched question.

Comment: But how can somebody down vote if they don't like the question, i had a doubt, i asked my community about it, somebody don't like my question, or found it's a duplicate, they have started to down vote , i don't get it

Comment: You're supposed to look for duplicates not make the rest of us do that for you. If you waste people's time and some of them will downvote you for it.

Comment: @RobertLongson i didn't know the word truncate, it was listed under this.. i am not that good with English, there are all types of users

Comment: I think , up votes should not be lost, but duplicated questions should not be allowed to downvote

Comment: You made things worse by invoking the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) by posting on Meta.

Comment: upvotes without downvotes isn't going to fly

Comment: But once marked duplicate, it is written duplicate on the title, still why down vote

Comment: I understood it from the beginning, but if you take a look at this, you can understand why i keep on asking         https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36660/most-down-voted-questions

Comment: if a guy tried hard to get some points, he realized that he made mistake and want to remove the post, what's wrong with that , these guys must have lost a lot

Comment: If a guy tried hard to write an answer why should we delete the post even though the question isn't very good?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete your own question when there are upvoted answers. Dupe or not.

Comment: okay i got it.........thanks

Answer (score 4):

Possibly due to the meta-effect the community might well end up deleting it - however, you've raised this as a mod flag (twice now) - the response was:

> Declined: I'm not deleting the good answers here.

Hopefully that says it all? Just because you're getting down votes on your question doesn't warrant destroying the work of others that have taken time to provide answers.

Comment: But how can somebody down vote if they don't like the question